# Listing data from multiple models in a flat table in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to display data from multiple models (Foreign key) as a table format.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

**Expected output:**

- Book 1 - isbn1 - Author1
- Book 1 - isbn1 - Author2
- Book 2 - isbn2 - Author3
- Book 3 - isbn3 - Author1

Now I am able to query the two models using various filters and have their corresponding list objects. How can I display these two list objects in the template with less code ?

One way I can think of is iterate through these two lists and create a list of dict with the corresponding keys for the columns and pass this list to the template. Is there a better approach to this ?

**Current Code**

```
def getresult(params):
    print "printing dict ", params
    titles  = params.getlist('titles')
    authors_input = params.getlist('authors')
    ...
    books = Book.objects.all()
    if len(title) > 0 :
        books = books.objects.filter(title__in = titles)
    ...
    authors = Authors.objects.filter(name__in=books)
    if len(authors_input) > 0 :
        authors  = authors.filter(name__in = authors_input)
    result = []
    for book in books:
        authors = authors.filter(name=book.author)
        for author in authors:
            output_item = {}
            output_item['book_name'] = book.title 
            output_item['isbn'] = book.isbn
            output_item['author'] = author.name
            result.append(output_item)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a common pattern, there is a [generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#generic-views-of-objects) that takes care of this. The code snippets here are directly from the documentation, modified for your unique case.

`urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import ListView
from myapp.models import Book

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^books/$', ListView.as_view(
        model=Book,
    )),
)
```

Create a template called `book_list.html` in a directory called `myapp` somewhere in a location that is in your `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

This snippet in the template (`book_list.html`) does what you need:

```
<ul>
{% for book in object_list %}
  {% for author in book.author_set.all %}
  <li>{{ book.title }}&mdash;{{ book.isbn }}&mdash;{{ author.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I filter the book and author objects based on my filter condition ?

Comment: Yes. Read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#generic-views-of-objects) on generic views.